# Qt Play the same video in five Phonon::VideoWidget

Tags: c++, qt, video, phonon

I'm trying to play the same video in five windows:

```
     Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::Widget)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
         media = new Phonon::MediaObject(this);
        media->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource("video.flv"));

        Phonon::VideoWidget* fvid=new Phonon::VideoWidget(this);
        Phonon::createPath(media,fvid);
        fvid->setGeometry(20,20,122,122);
        fvid->show();

        Phonon::VideoWidget* fvid2=new Phonon::VideoWidget(this);
        Phonon::createPath(media,fvid2);
        fvid2->setGeometry(220,220,122,122);
        fvid2->show();
    }

void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    media->play();
}
```

This code works for one VideoWidget, but not for two or five. If I create several Mediaobjects,  my cpu usage goes up to 70-90%. The same task was solved in FLash for browsers. But I need solution for C++ Qt. I dont have any others ideas. 
The video.flv is 144x144 and its duration is about 7-8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Phonon supports *frame grabbing*, but a better idea is to have **only one Phonon player**, and then you would make a copy of each frame being renderended to a `QImage` object. You could then copy the `QImage` to another 4 `QLabel` objects, one for each of the 4 windows.

This solution uses a lot less CPU processing since you will be only rendering one video.

The truth is that **Phonon is dying,** and [Qt Mobility](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0/multimedia.html) offers [QMediaPlayer/QVideoWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0/multimedia.html#video) which are simple to work with and allows *frame grabbing*. I suggest you move your application to this technology.